# color box hover css html

Tags: html, css

i try to apply hover on box .. means when i drag mouse over menu items then background color must be change so for that i try this code please check

i try this

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.lefttabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: medium;
  color: White;
  width: 133px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.lefttabs ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.lefttabs li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}
.lefttabs li a {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}
.lefttabs a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: green;
  background-color: White;
  border-color: Yellow;
  color: #000!important;
  height: 20%;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lefttabs" style="width: 187px; height: 422px;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>DASHBOARD</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a> EVENTS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

In the above image i hover box but this not completely fill whereas i draw box with white color so i want to fill that box through hover
any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to display your `padding` to your `a` tag and not to your `li` tag.

```
.lefttabs li
{
   list-style:none;
}

.lefttabs li  a 
{
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Add `border: 1px solid`